# How to capture a screenshot out of an overlay on Android in Java

Tags: java, android, screen, screenshot, capture

I coded an Java-pplication for android the last days. It should take a bitmap of the screen when a user clicks the overlay button. The permissions are all fine, the overlay works as intendet but when you click on it, it creates a bitmap from the app itself, not from the actual screen. How can I change this so the bitmap is created from the actual scren?

I searched a lot but didn't find a bit of code which worked well. Thank you for your help.

Heres my code:

```java
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(@NonNull View view) {
    view = getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

```java
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), loadBitmapFromView(v), getCurrentTimestampAsFileName() , "");
    //stuff to move overlay button
    return true;
});
```

Comment: "it creates a bitmap from the app itself, not from the actual screen" -- your app does not have access to the actual screen directly. Use the media projection APIs to take a screenshot of the device screen.

Comment: Is this the way, screen capture apps create screenshots?

Comment: Yes. FWIW, I cover the media projection APIs in [this free older book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/).